# What does "while test $# -gt 0" do?

Tags: shell-script, function

I'm trying to create a function and believe I found a good working example but I don't understand all the logic behind it.

More specifically, on the "while" line, could someone explain what test is and does? what is $# (isn't # a comment char?) and were does the -gt 0 parameter comes from? couldn't find it in the while man page.

Here is the example:

```
function my_function()
{
while test $# -gt 0
do
    $
echo "$1"
    shift
done
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. They were all very useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While `#` on it's own is definitely a comment, `$#` contains the number of parameters passed to your function.

`test` is an program which lets you perform various tests, for example, if one number is greater than another number (if your operator is `-gt`; there are many other operators, see `man test`). It will return success if the the test is successful (in this case, if `the number of parameters` IS greater than 0).

the `shift` command throws away the first parameter. It also decreases `$#`

The code as a whole can be seen as: do something with a parameter (in this case, showing it on the screen), then discard it; repeat until there are no parameters left.

If you want to see all the parameters that are left, useful for debugging, check the contents of `$@`

Comment: I would also like to add this excellent [reference](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php)

Answer (score 5):

`$#` ==> script parameters passed

`test` ==> condition evaluation command

`-gt` ==> represents *greater than*

`test a -gt b` ==> true if a is greater than b, false otherwise

Putting it all together:

`while test $# -gt 0` ==> while there are more parameters passed (the reason why this is changing is because of shift)

What make things tricky is `shift` within the body of the while loop.

`$1` ==> represents always the first parameter

To make this more concrete, let's say you are passing parameters `a`, `b` and `c`.

`$1` ==> represents `a` as this is your first parameter

by calling now `shift`, `a` is gone and your parameter list is now `b` and `c` therefore if you invoke `$1` now it's `b` since this is now the first parameter in the list. Invoking `shift` once more your parameter list is now just `c`, therefore `$1` is now `c`. Calling `shift` one more time leaves the parameter list empty therefore the while condition will not success (as the parameter list if not greater than 0 anymore as it's now zero in size) which will cause the while loop to terminate.

*What are the gains of using `shift` and referring to the current parameter as `$1`?*

It gives you the flexibility not to know in advance in your script how many parameters are passed in the script and regardless of that to iterate through them one by one referring within the while loop to the current param always as `$1` since that means the head of the parameter list. By `shift`ing eventually the parameter list will be empty therefore it's important to have the while condition to check whether it's greater than zero in order to terminate and not infinitely loop.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below script to understand what the variables mean. Save the script as `somescript.sh` and call the script with some input parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I display the total parameters passed to this script from commandline"
echo $#
echo "I display all the parameter values"
echo "Input: $@"
echo "I display the first parameter value"
echo "$1"

shift 
echo "After shift: $@"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll forgive me a bit of answer recycling, I think you may find this useful.

```
_fn() { set -- "$@" $(cat)
    while ${1+:} false ; do 
        echo "$1" && [ "$1" = "arg2" ] && echo "$1"
        $YOUR_CHK
        shift
    done
}

echo "arg2" | _fn "arg1"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
arg1
arg2
arg2
```

That handles both cmd-line args and `stdin`. It only runs the `while` loop to check them while you still have at least one argument saved in your parameter array. It does discard every argument it checks, so part of `$YOUR_CHK` should be saving information you think valuable in one way or another.

`_fn` would behave the same if its contents were the body of a script, or as is in the form of a shell function.

`_fn` handles `stdin` - in this case `"arg2" echo`ed over the `|pipe` - in the first line by `set`ting its positional parameter shell `$@`array to everything passed on the command-line - or `"$@"` - AND everything `cat` spits out via `$(comand substitution)`.

`while _fn's $1` first parameter is `${set+}` we substitute the shell's built-in `:true` to satisfy the `while` loop conditional. As soon as `$1` is unset that substitution fails to happen, the conditional evaluates to `false` and the `while` loop breaks.

For every iteration of the `while` loop the `_fn() echo`es its `$1` first parameter `&&` if successful (`echo` is *always* successful) `[ tests ]` to see if `$1` equals the string `"arg2"` `&&` if the `[ test ]` is successful `_fn() echo`es `$1` again.

`$YOUR_CHK` is a null-op - it is an unset variable that evaluates to nothing before ever the shell executes any code.

For every iteration of the `while` loop we `shift` away the `$1` first parameter. So on iteration 1 `"$@"` looks like:

```
arg1 arg2
```

But after we `shift` the first time it looks like:

```
arg2
```

And after we `shift` the last time it looks like:

So this brings us back around again to `${1+:} false` - because `$1` is now unset the shell will not substitute `:true` and instead only `false` is evaluated, which breaks the `while` loop and ends the `_fn().`